# draft.js, html2canvas RangeError: NaN is not a valid code point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas, draftjs, html2pdf

I'm using [html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/) (which uses *html2canvas* library) in my React project.
I need to export the content of [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) editor to pdf for which I'm using the following code:

```
    const el = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
    const opt = {
      margin:       1,
      filename:     'myfile.pdf',
      pagebreak:    { mode: ['avoid-all']},
      image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 1},
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(el).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
      var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
      for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pdf.setPage(i);
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.setTextColor(150);
        pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, 1, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.3);
      } 
    }).save();
```

This mostly works, the problem occures only when the editor contains ordered list with more than one item, in that case, the app freezes on export (needs to be refreashed to start working again) and I get `RangeError: NaN is not a valid code point` error in the console.
It seems to be because, at some point, the `fromCodePoint` function in *html2canvas* receives the NaN value, but I have no idea where it came from.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works as expected. Maybe you've accidentally removed code from the example which causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

(Forgot to post the solution sooner, but hopefully, someone finds this helpful)
I didn't manage to fix the problem, but this bypass works well:

```
const el = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
// Replace ordered lists with placeholders to avoid html2canvas counter-reset bug
el.querySelectorAll('ol').forEach(ol => {
  ol.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li, i) => {
    li.style.counterReset = 'none';
    li.classList.add('pdf-print-li');
    li.setAttribute('data-counter', `${i + 1}. `);
  });
});

const opt = {
  margin: 1,
  filename: `${meetingTitle}.pdf`,
  pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all'] },
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
  html2canvas: { scale: 1 },
  jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

html2pdf()
  .from(el)
  .set(opt)
  .toPdf()
  .get('pdf')
  .then(function (pdf) {
    // Return ordered lists to previous state
    el.querySelectorAll('ol').forEach(ol => {
      ol.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li, i) => {
        li.style.counterReset = null;
        li.classList.remove('pdf-print-li');
        li.removeAttribute('data-counter');
      });
    });
   };
```